# jQuery append on hover is called twice

Tags: jquery, append

I'm trying to achieve something like you have in the back end of Wordpress where when you hover over a row in the the table of posts, it displays the edit, trash and preview links.

However, when I try this, it appends the links twice which is a bit of a problem. I read that the hover fires functions off twice on hover in chrome, but tried it in opera and the same error occurred so I don't think that's the problem.

[Here](http://qwibbledesigns.co.uk/preview/Admin/tabular.html) is a demo of it.

And here is the code

```
// Table row hover displays links

$('table.tablesorter tbody tr').hover( 
     function() {  // mouseover 
          $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').append('<p class="links"><a>Edit</a><a>Preview</a><a>Delete</a></p>'); 
     }, 
     function() {  // mouseout 
          $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').find('p.links').remove(); 
     } 
   );
```

Can you see why it adds the links twice instead of once?

Comment: It happens in Firefox too. No idea why, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have included `js/custom.jquery.js` twice. Once in the `head` and once after `body` is closed. The same with `jquery`

Comment: Oh man, I am so forgetful. I added the scripts to the bottom of each page, but forgot to remove them from the top in all but the first page I did >.>

Thanks for picking that up man, would of puzzled me for ages lol

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't answer your question but you could hide your <p> when the mouse is out and show it when the mouse is over.

Answer (score 2):

Creating elements on mouseover/mouseout is much more work on the browser then having those elements created (already in the markup with `display:none;` ) and showing/hiding them. your mouseover and mouseout are probably BOTH firing and it can't find the element to remove and continues to add it..

```
$('table.tablesorter tbody tr').hover( 
     function() {  // mouseover 
          $(this).find('.myControls').fadeIn(); 
     }, 
     function() {  // mouseout 
          $(this).find('.myControls').fadeOut(); 
     } 
   );
```

Comment: So it's probably a better idea to have the links within every single row of the table, hide them all by default, and then show it when you hover over its row?

Answer (score 0):

you have to check it you get the same object or not

example:

```
$('#updateCart').on('mouseenter', function (event) {
        if (event.handled !== true) { .....
                  //Put your code in here
          }
}
```